# Standard way around unimplemented getBlob in xerial/SQLIte for Slick/Scala?

Tags: scala, sqlite, slick

I am using Scala/Slick (2.12/3.2) to query a table with Blob types. The `slick.codegen.SourceCodeGenerator` generated the Column type as `Rep[Option[java.sql.Blob]]` . But when I try to query it I get

```
java.sql.SQLException: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver
  at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4ResultSet.unused(JDBC4ResultSet.java:333)
  at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4ResultSet.getBlob(JDBC4ResultSet.java:356)
```

Looking at the source, getBlob just throws an exception. https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/issues/135 confirms getBlob is unimplemented. Given that, what is the standard way with scala/slick to get Blob data out of a sqlite db? Are there standard alternatives to xerial or should I modify the autogen code?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [hex() function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#hex) to return the blob as text (you then have to convert it back in your code):

```sql
SELECT hex(MyBlobColumn) FROM ...
```

Comment: I suppose this answers the question I asked, but what I really should have asked was how to get blobs out with Slick :) . Writing raw SQL makes it harder to play nice with rest of the code (maybe I am just inexperienced with Slick) .